# Math competitions resource at university level

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, online-resources

I want some problems especially in Algebra field for math competitions at undergraduate math students level. Does anybody here know book, website,... that I can use?!

Comment: Putnam is your best bet if you live in the US or Canada.

Comment: I want problems with solution for using in real competitions.

Comment: Best I could find solutions is here http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/.

Answer (score 1):

1. Site: MSE is a family oriented site that teaches you the math that you wish to learn but not normally taught at schools. For sites that rivals MSE I think *the arts of problem solving* is popular, and they specialized in math olympiad stuffs. So they are what you are looking for.
2. Books: The collection of Putnam problems is what every wannabe olympian would like to have on his or her bookshelf, but they are hard for beginners unless you have some level of experience in IMO. I am neither an IMO nor Putnam contestant so my advice is limited in scope.
   In the area of math competitions, the lead figure is Titu Andreescu. He is running a site called *Awesomemath.org.* Here you again can find books, and articles that you need to read for your algebra ambition.

Cheerio !